# SilverStripe 4 with fluent: "Table 'ss4_project.Member_Localised' doesn't exist"

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've got fresh project using SilverStripe 4.8 and fluent 5.0.0. I've added an extension to the Member and the fluent extension with fields to translate:

```yaml
SilverStripe\Security\Member:
  extensions:
    - MemberExtension
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension
  translate:
    - ShortDesc
    - Description
```

Seems pretty standard, but I get `Table 'ss4_project.Member_Localised' doesn't exist` during dev/build. I've tried without the translate fields as well as in a different configuration loaded after the member extension. No luck.

I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Any clues are appreciated.

Comment: Seems like something else wants to query Member before the localised table is created. If you have xdebug installed on your dev environment you'll see a backtrace. There you should be able to detect the source of the Member query.

Comment: @wmk There is a table protection for core tables I wasn't aware of. This reply by tractorcow pointed me in the right direction: https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent/issues/725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Github, I've got the following solution:

```
Security::force_database_is_ready(false); // only during dev/build
```

to switch of the protection for core table temporary.

For details see https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent/issues/725